# Удаление словаря из массива Mongodb по номеру (pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

В коллекции есть массив со словарями:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "576502aca43aa11ca48bb8d5"
},
"event_name": "Тестовое",
"participants": [
    {
        "name": "Участник 1",
        "start_debt": 2500,
        "income": 0,
        "debt": 2500
    },
    {
        "name": "Участник 2",
        "start_debt": 2500,
        "income": 0,
        "debt": 2500
    },
    {
        "name": "Участник 3",
        "start_debt": 2500,
        "income": 0,
        "debt": 2500
    },
    {
        "name": "Участник 3",
        "start_debt": 2500,
        "income": 0,
        "debt": 2500
    }
],
"debt": 10000,
"income": 0,
"budget": 10000}
```

Нужно удалить элемент из массива(словарь) именно по порядковому номеру.

Пытался сделать таким образом:

```
data_base.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(event_id)},
                                 {'$pull': {'participants': 2}})
```

Естественно результата не добился.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напрямую удалить элемент по индексу пока нельзя, смотрите ишью https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1014.

Но можно обойти с помощью двух последовательных команд:

```
mongo.db.collection.update({}, {'$unset': {'participants.2':1}})
mongo.db.collection.update({}, {'$pull': {'participants': None}})
```

Сначала заменяем нужный элемент (в данном случае с индексом 2) на null, затем второй командой удаляем его.

Большой минус - действия не атомарные, и после выполнения первого, какое то время в массиве будет элемент со значением null.
Если это критично, то верный способ это вручную считать/модифицировать/записать документ.

Comment: Да, ваш способ работает. Но вышел из ситуации присвоением id каждому элементу массива.

Comment: @Oleksii, если есть возможность добавить уникальный id и использовать его для `$pull`, это будет самый лучший способ (я исходил из того, что вы не можете повлиять на структуру данных).

Comment: Да, вы все правильно поняли. До последнего надеялся на возможность обойтись без id. Ан нет.